# gspread output and sting manipulation with Python

Tags: python, gspread

I used gspread to get some data from a Google docs spreadsheet.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
worksheet_2 = sp1.get_worksheet(1)
worksheet_1 = sp1.get_worksheet(0)

val = worksheet_2.acell('F2')

print val
```

when I print `val` the output is:  `<Cell R2C6 '76'>`.

I am just after the val its self which in this case is `76`.

**Q:** How can manipulate the string with python to just get 76 *(or the number inside the single quotes)* from `<Cell R2C6 '76'>` or with `gspread`?

I will then use this value with a letter and concatenate them to be used for updating a cell.

***Ideally:*** The number will be concatenated with a letter to be used in the following line in to append new information, something like this:

```
val = worksheet_2.acell('F2')

letter = A

cell_location = letter+val

print cell_location

worksheet_1.update_acell('cell_location',"Sheet 111")
```

Comment: you can use regex library `re` with a pattern like `"'[^']+'"` to match anything inside of the quotes or `"'\d+'"` to match only numbers

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific command to just get the value:

```
val = worksheet_2.acell('H2').value
```

The overall code would something like this:

```
worksheet_1 = sp1.get_worksheet(0)
worksheet_2 = sp1.get_worksheet(1)

val = worksheet_2.acell('H2').value

column = "B"
cell_coordinate = column+val
print cell_coordinate

worksheet_1.update_acell(cell_coordinate,"Sheet 111")
```

The first two lines are for the individual worksheets of the spreadsheet.
`val = worksheet_2.acell('H2').value` gets *only* the value from cell `H2` and assigns that value to the variable `val`. The variable `column` is assigned `B` and `val` and `column` variables are concatenated together before being printed as `cell_coordinate`. This coordinates are used to print "sheet 111" in the new `cell_coordinate`